# Querying an Xml Document for elements using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using XDocument to work with XML data.
My Xml has the following structure

```
<Info>
 <ProductDetails>
    <ProductDetail>
      <ProductId>123</ProductId>
      <ProductName>Test</ProductName>
      <ProductType>1</ProductType>
      <AccountDetails>
        <AccountType>Single</AccountType>
        <AccountDetail>
          <AccountId>8564</AccountId>
        </AccountDetail>
      </AccountDetails>
    </ProductDetail>
  </ProductDetails>
</Info>
```

I want to retrieve the AccountDetails section in the XML based on a particular element Id and then replace it with some other XML content.
I tried something like

```
xdoc.Root.Element("ProductDetails").Element("ProductDetail").Element("ProductId").Value
```

What will be the best way to achieve this

Comment: Well you need "ProductDetails" rather than "PrductDetails"... and `Value` rather than `value`. You also haven't said what happened when you tried. Please give us a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: In addition to Jon Skeet's suggestion to provide good sample of the problem, please explain what kind of "the best way" you are looking for - performance, readability, easy to write, something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find the first `ProductDetail` element with a given product ID. This would do the trick for that:

```
public XElement FindProduct(XDocument doc, int id)
{
    return doc.Descendants("ProductId")
              .Where(pid => (int) pid == id)
              .Select(pid => pid.Parent)
              .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This will return `null` if it doesn't find the relevant product. Note that it will *not* detect the presence of multiple products with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind a extended version of first answer:

```
public void UpdateAccountDetails(XDocument doc, int id,XElement newContent)
 {
  var element = doc.Descendants("ProductDetail")
          .Where(p => (int)p.Element("ProductId").Value == id)
          .Select(p => p)
          .FirstOrDefault();
  if (element != null) {
      element.Element("AccountDetails").ReplaceWith(newContent);
      doc.Save(path);

 }

}
```